# Any difference between `self.backgroundcolor` and `self.layer.backgroundcolor`?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

```
@implementation AVSuperView

- (AVSuperView*)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
//        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        AVLayout* avLayout = [[AVLayout alloc] init];
```

In a custom UIView, e.g. above, it seems the `self.backgroundColor` and `self.layer.backgroundColor` is the same. Is `self.backgroundColor` a wrapper for `self.layer.backgroundColor`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is `self.backgroundColor` a wrapper for `self.layer.backgroundColor`?

Yes, that is exactly what it is. The same is true of `frame`, of `alpha` and `opacity`, and various other properties (not to mention the fact that the drawing in the view is actually the drawing in the layer).

A view and its underlying layer are very initimately bound up. In a sense, the view exists only to endow the layer with the ability to receive touches.

Comment: You might want to look over the discussion in my online book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch16.html#_view_and_layer